# Mysql Stop running OPTIMIZE command?

Tags: mysql, optimization, kill

About 1hr ago I started MySQL optimize on a MyISAM table. which is ~20G with 250M rows. For now it is creating db_name.TMD which is 1G and growing.

As I understand MySQL is now recreating an optimized copy of my table, if my assumption is right  killing the optimization process should not damage the 
original DB?? 
Also how do I kill only the optimization process?
And What Happens if disk space runs out during optimization???

BTW. I just checked process-list and current state: Repair with keycache. 
Ok more questions: 
The Table  I started optimize on has: 10442MB .MYD file and 9319M .MYI  what amount of space will the optimize process take? ~ .MYD file size or MYD + MYI file size?

Comment: Why are you running `OPTIMIZE`?  It is almost never needed.

Comment: There is a setting to get it to use "repair by sorting" instead.  This should be much faster (but not prevent running out of disk space).

Comment: On a second machine I change settings, did repair by sorting which took only about 1hrs.
As for why I ran optimize, of pure interest if it would optimize space. which it did ~1.5G from MYI file.

Comment: A 20GB table will take about 20GB of extra disk space to do `OPTIMIZE`; maybe more, maybe less.  It's like a progress bar -- it can't be precise without doing the entire task.

Comment: 1.5 / 9.3 saved -- (1) you'll lose the space as more rows are inserted, (2) queries won't speed up much.  (3) Was it worth the effort?

Answer (score 5):

I've stopped the optimize process a number of times in the past, without adverse effects. However, I did have a backup available in case of problems.

To stop the process, I used `KILL process_id` where `process_id` is taken from the results of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

The amount of space needed by the optimization depends on the number of rows marked as deleted in your table.

Comment: I also stopped the process, since I ran out of space, but the database was marked as crashed. copying currently to another computer with lot's of free space to do repair and optimize